# Inserting Images from user input in table as sidebar python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I am trying to create two different word template using python-docx.
I have complete the first one and second one is almost same just it add table of images from left side and I i have tried but not succeed in second one.

Here is Image of Second Format :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PodYO.jpg
This one is Image of Format One Completed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLBHy.jpg

This is code I have used in format one which is completed and working.
But I am not sure what to do with second table images using user input.

```
def single_image_format(title,dep_name,des_text,image,filename):
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading(title, 0)
    document.add_heading(dep_name, 2)
    document.add_paragraph(des_text)
    my_image = document.add_picture(image,width=Inches(0.8))
    document.save(filename+'.docx')
```

This is my first experience with python-docx.

Comment: Please post links to images, not galleries

Comment: How do you run the function? What happens?

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Please Input all correct data and Make sure image path is correct too.")
    name = input("Enter Title : ")
    dep_n = input("Enter Department Name : ")
    des_t = input("Enter Your Complete Description Text : ")
    img = input("Input Image path")
    f_name = input("Input Filename you want to create : ")
    single_image_format(name,dep_n,des_t,img,f_name)

Comment: As I have mentioned above this code is working I am just not sure about the image table with user input and Table should be sidebar as shown in image of second format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-docx` does not support "floating" aka. "absolute position" items (not yet anyway) such as the table shown in the image you linked to. Consequently, what you're trying to do is not possible using the current `python-docx` API.

Comment: Is there any other python library I can use for this ?